# How do I enforce a unifrom company email font and signature format across Outlook 2007, 10 and 13?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, fonts, active-directory, group-policy

Our users currently run a mixture of Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 to manage emails. We use active directory and our server runs Windows Server 2008 R2.

Is there anyway that we can enforce through either group policy, or through additional software, a way of locking the style of our email signatures and also the font formatting of the body text. We are having issues with users changing fonts and emails being sent out that look inconsistent.

We would need to allow some users to be exempt from this rule AND allow all users to maintain multiple signatures since some people  work across departments.

If for any reason you can only recommend a solution that works on Outlook 2010 and 2013 that would be ok since we can upgrade the 2007 users.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATED TO ADD SPECIFICS:

Moderators have suggested that I was not specific enough. The exact problem is that our users can send out emails to clients with whatever formatting they like - this leads to a lack of consistency in outgoing emails and, as such, impacts the professional image of the company. To resolve this we wish to set for our users the formatting they must use when replying to all emails through Outlook 2010, 2013 and OWA. The formatting we choose should be enforced when composing a new email and when replying to any non-plain text email.

In terms of the signature, we want to provide each user with a signature and not allow them to change it as again we have noticed inconsistencies in the current scenarios.

We must be able to exclude certain users from this enforcement since there are legitimate use cases where someone needs either multiple signatures, or to use different formatting.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Some links which may be useful for you: - [Enforcing a default font and theme](http://www.itninja.com/blog/view/enforcing-a-default-font-and-theme-in-outlook-2010-with-group-policy-preferences) - [Setting up a corporate signature](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/corporatesignatures.htm) - [Centrally managing Signatures in Outlook and OWA](http://www.edugeek.net/blogs/thescarfedone/1016-centrally-managing-signatures-outlook-owa-free-way.html)

Comment: Our IT administrator is looking at this to see how applicable they are and I will mark the answer as complete if they fit, if they don't I will list why they do not in the hope of alternatives.

Comment: We use Symprex Mail Signature Manager. It pulls details out of AD, inserts an image into the signature as well as a "please respect the environment" line, etc. We use it to set an "internal" (name, job title) and "external" (name, job, address, phone number, the whole 5 years). I don't know how much it was but it seems to work well.

Comment: [sf] is the proper place to ask questions on this topic.  See http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask